# Why don't shears work on leaves in Creative mode?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm in Minecraft and I try to use [Shears](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Shear) on a [Jungle Trees](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Tree#Jungle_trees) leaves, while I'm in Creative Mode and it isn't working.  Is this planned not to be in the game?

- **Why isn't it working?**

Comment: If you have cheats enabled, just do /gamemode survival, shear the leaves then use /gamemode creative

Comment: @SomeWittyUsername actually, `/gamemode c` and `/gamemode s` is enough.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In creative mode, you destroy anything in one hit, regardless of tool. To get jungle leaves find them in the menu, or use center click (push down on the scroll wheel) on leaves.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to press "t"(to open chat, if your key is different, press that), type /gamemode 0 and press enter. This will change you to survival mode, just make sure you re-type the command with 1 before the zombies get you!